# Selecting previous element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

This is my code,

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbx" name="cbx">
    </td>
    <td>
        <div>some content</div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="book">Book now</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have around 20 table rows similar to this in my page. What I want to do is, When I click on the span tag which is in the 3rd td in the row, the checkbox should be checked which is in the same row.

I've tried this but its not working,

```
$('.book').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().find('.cbx').attr('checked',true);
});
```

Please help me short this,

Regards.

Comment: `$(this).parent()` will only look inside that `<td>`. Either `.parent()` twice or do a more elegant solution such as roXon's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, Using `.closest()` method find the `tr` than go search for your `.cbx` ! :)

```
$('.book').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.cbx').prop('checked',true);
});
```

your example was pointing to your `TD` element cause you were using only `.parent()`.
To reach the `TR` instead of using `.parent().parent()` use just `.closest('tr')`

http://api.jquery.com/closest/
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thank you soooooo much roxon. Its working like a charm. Sorry I cant vote you up coz of my status.

Comment: @user1915190 you cannot vote but you can accept answers! by clicking the **'V'** checkmark near the *vote arrows*

Comment: @user1915190 THX :) you did vote but you did not accepted the answer as correct one. :|

Comment: It says to wait another 5 minutes

Comment: @user1915190 sure, that allows you to see more answers before deciding who to give cudos for the (fastest or) most-useful answer

Answer (score 1):

In your code `.parent()` will select parent `<td>` node. In order to select `<tr>`, you should use either `.parent().parent()` or `.closest("tr")`:

```
$(".book").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".cbx").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Note, it is better to apply `.prop("checked", true)` or `.attr("checked", "checked")`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be simple done with

```
$( '.book' ).on( 'click', function() {
    var $tr = $( this ).parents( 'tr' ).eq( 0 );
    // get the parenting tr

    $( '.cbx', $tr ).attr( 'checked', true );
    // select elements matching '.cbx' inside of $tr and check them
} );
```